# How can I change the format of timezone.now in django?

Tags: python, django

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User




class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Title",max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Content")
    publish_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I have this bunch of code and in `publish_date` I want date to be shown as I want but I cant format it,any solution please? For now,it outputs the data like this `2020-07-17` but I want to show day or month first.Thanks

Comment: `timezone.now` has no format. It is not a string, it simply is a timestamp. You can for example in the template use the `|date` template tag to format it properly: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks for reply mate.But I'm creating rest api not a template

Comment: then it is in the format of the serializer.

Comment: see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datefield

Comment: I dont know but I'm using `django.utills.timezone` as I sent.Nothing related to serializer

Comment: why not `models.DateField(format="%d-%m-%Y" default=timezone.now)` ?

Comment: @Vipkry: The model fields *have* no format attribute, since a stored datetime has no format. The *serializer* field has a format parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually change how it is displayed to your **templates** by using django builtin pipes. see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date